# Как правильно оформить евангельское послание?

Tags: оформление-текста

> Некоторые авторы считают, что одно из посланий Павла – а именно
>   второе
>    «К Тимофею»,  – непосредственное обращение к сыну хозяина этого дома
>   <сенатора Пуденция>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Некоторые авторы считают, что одно из посланий Павла, **а именно второе «К Тимофею»,** – (это) непосредственное обращение к сыну хозяина этого дома <сенатора Пуденция>.

Пояснительный **союзный** оборот можно обособить запятыми, а тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: Оно гуглится так: *Второе послание к Тимофею святого апостола Павла; Труд блаженного Феофилакта Болгарского «Толкование на Второе послание к Тимофею святого апостола Павла»; 2-е послание к Тимофею святого апостола Павла; «Толкование на 2-е послание к Тимофею» — часть «Толкового Апостола» Феофана Затворника*, то есть гуляют прописные-строчные, цифра и слово... И никаких кавычек однако.